# Group figures with square bracket with vertical text on left side

Tags: floats, captions, subfig, vertical

I have 12 subfigures (of identical dimensions) displayed in a page, arranged in 4 rows of 3 each. I'm using the "subfigure" environment, which is working perfectly for this purpose. Actually, I would like to add some vertical text, rotated by 90°, on the left side of each two rows of subfigures, possibly next to a square bracket or another way useful to group them. For better understanding what I'd like to do, see the red parts in the figure.[image]

I'm attaching the code I'm using for plotting the subfigures here:

```
\documentclass{article}[hyperref]
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
     \centering
 \begin{subfigure}{0.33\textwidth}
     \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-empty}
     \caption{caption 1ss}
 \end{subfigure}\hfill
 \begin{subfigure}{0.33\textwidth}
     \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-empty}
     \caption{caption 1sg}
 \end{subfigure}\hfill
 \begin{subfigure}{0.33\textwidth}
     \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-empty}
     \caption{caption 1sd}
 \end{subfigure}
 \medskip
 \begin{subfigure}{0.33\textwidth}
     \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-empty}
     \caption{caption 1ts}
 \end{subfigure}\hfill
 \begin{subfigure}{0.33\textwidth}
     \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-empty}
     \caption{caption 1tg}
 \end{subfigure}\hfill
 \begin{subfigure}{0.33\textwidth}
     \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-empty}
     \caption{caption 1td}
 \end{subfigure}
 \medskip
 \begin{subfigure}{0.33\textwidth}
     \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-empty}
     \caption{caption 2ss}
 \end{subfigure}\hfill
 \begin{subfigure}{0.33\textwidth}
     \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-empty}
     \caption{caption 2sg}
 \end{subfigure}\hfill
 \begin{subfigure}{0.33\textwidth}
     \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-empty}
     \caption{caption 2sd}
 \end{subfigure}
 \medskip
 \begin{subfigure}{0.33\textwidth}
     \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-empty}
     \caption{caption 2ts}
 \end{subfigure}\hfill
 \begin{subfigure}{0.33\textwidth}
     \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-empty}
     \caption{caption 2tg}
 \end{subfigure}\hfill
 \begin{subfigure}{0.33\textwidth}
     \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-empty}
     \caption{caption 2td}
 \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

For the sake of showing you I've loaded the package mwe to have sample images.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code snippet compilable (that is, add `\documentclass` and necessary packages to it).

Comment: Your `\documentclass` command is incomplete. The mandatory argument is missing. Moreover `\begin{document}` before `\documentclass` is obviously wrong. Please test your example before posting it, to make sure, that it is a [minimal *working* example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964). BTW: As we do not have your image files, you should, e.g., use the example images from package [`mwe`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mwe) or load package `graphicx` with option `demo`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also with `tikzmark` library, but with square bracket, use of `Gin` keys and for `\tikzmarknode` use whole `subfigure` (just first two rows of images):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[skip=0.5ex, belowskip=1ex]{subcaption}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,
                tikzmark}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
     \centering
     \setkeys{Gin}{width=0.95\linewidth}
\tikzmarknode{A}{~\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth} % observe ~ before subfigure
     \includegraphics{example-image-empty}
     \caption{caption 1ss}
\end{subfigure}}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
     \includegraphics{example-image-empty}
     \caption{caption 1sg}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
     \includegraphics{example-image-empty}
     \caption{caption 1sd}
\end{subfigure}

 \medskip
\tikzmarknode{B}{~\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}  % observe ~ before subfigure
     \includegraphics{example-image-empty}
     \caption{caption 1ts}
 \end{subfigure}}
\hfill
 \begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
     \includegraphics{example-image-empty}
     \caption{caption 1tg}
 \end{subfigure}
\hfill
 \begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
     \includegraphics{example-image-empty}
     \caption{caption 1td}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

%%%% drawing square bracket
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \path[draw=purple, thick, text=purple, scale=1.2]
         ([xshift=10mm] B.south west) -- (B.south west) to["${GWL=+1}$", sloped] ([yshift=1mm] A.north west) -- ++ (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

For final result are needed three compilation (at least).

Comment: Thank you so much! It solved my tricky problem!

Answer (score 2):

This code will draw the braces and associated text using the `tikz` package. First adds four `tikzmarks` on the figure structure to use as reference points. Then draws the two braces and the text using a `tikzpicture`.
(the red color can be changed by removing the word "red" or using another color)

To make everything fit in the text area, the `\hfill`  has been changed to a fixed space, images have been decreased in size, and the entire layout has been flushed to the right to make room for the braces.

In this example, only the necessary packages were loaded.
[image: c]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}% needed <<<<<<<<<<
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark} % needed <<<<<<<<<<
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing} % needed <<<<<<<<<<}
\usepackage[skip=0.5ex, belowskip=1ex]{subcaption}

\usepackage{mwe}

%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{amsthm}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}
%\usepackage{bookmark}
%\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{multirow}
%\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{showframe}% ONLY to show the margins

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htbp]
        %   \centering
        \flushright %to make room for the braces
        \begin{subfigure}{0.30\textwidth}\tikzmark{a}\par%changed <<<<<<<<<<<
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-empty}
            \caption{caption 1ss}
        \end{subfigure}\enspace
        \begin{subfigure}{0.30\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-empty}
            \caption{caption 1sg}
        \end{subfigure}\enspace
        \begin{subfigure}{0.30\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-empty}
            \caption{caption 1sd}
        \end{subfigure}
    
        \medskip            
        \begin{subfigure}{0.30\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-empty}
            \tikzmark{d}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\caption{caption 1ts}%changed <<<<<<<<<<<
        \end{subfigure}\enspace
        \begin{subfigure}{0.30\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-empty}
            \caption{caption 1tg}
        \end{subfigure}\enspace
        \begin{subfigure}{0.30\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-empty}
            \caption{caption 1td}
        \end{subfigure}
    
        \medskip            
        \begin{subfigure}{0.30\textwidth}\tikzmark{g}\par%changed <<<<<<<<<<<
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-empty}
            \caption{caption 2ss}
        \end{subfigure}\enspace
        \begin{subfigure}{0.30\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-empty}
            \caption{caption 2sg}
        \end{subfigure}\enspace
        \begin{subfigure}{0.30\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-empty}
            \caption{caption 2sd}
        \end{subfigure}
    
        \medskip            
        \begin{subfigure}{0.30\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-empty}
            \tikzmark{j}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\caption{caption 2ts}%changed <<<<<<<<<<<
        \end{subfigure}\enspace
        \begin{subfigure}{0.30\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-empty}
            \caption{caption 2tg}
        \end{subfigure}\enspace
        \begin{subfigure}{0.30\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-empty}
            \caption{caption 2td}
        \end{subfigure} 
        
    \end{figure}
    
    %********************************************* added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,thick]
        \draw[decorate, decoration={brace,mirror, raise=5pt, amplitude=5pt,},red] % change the color <<<<
        ({pic cs:a})  -- node[left , inner ysep=1.3em, rotate=90,anchor= south] {GWL = +1}  (pic cs:d);
        \draw[decorate, decoration={brace,mirror, raise=5pt, amplitude=5pt,},red] 
        ({pic cs:g})  -- node[left , inner ysep=1.3em, rotate=90,anchor= south] {GWL = +2} (pic cs:j);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    %*********************************************
    
\end{document}
```